# Is this preg_replace example exploitable in any way?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, exploit

Is this code explotable in any way?

```
<?
$arg=$_REQUEST['arg'];
preg_replace("/([0-9]+)(.+)/e",'list($var,$var2)=array("$1","$2")',$arg);
echo "$var - $var2";
?>
```

Is it possible to use special characters or some other method to inject code?

I'm using similar code in some projects and I just want to make sure that it is safe.

Comment: Why would you think it is unsafe?

Comment: Do not use the `e` modifier, it's deprecated and could lead to exploited code. Use `preg_replace_callback()` instead.

Comment: There is code being run which is created using user input. (I actually believe it is safe but I'm a bit worried that there might be some exploits I'm unaware of.)

Comment: I 'm sorry, but there is no real question here. Pasting random code snippets and asking "is this safe?" is an abuse of SO -- you might get your answer, but noone else is going to benefit from it. If you have adequate reason or even just a suspicion to believe that this code is unsafe, explain your misgivings and ask a specific question.

Comment: I'm sure preg_replace is often used in with the modifier e. I modified my question. Is it clear enough now or is there any way I can improve it?

Comment: @B.Martin: It's better. It's also trivially exploitable: `?arg={${eval($_GET[php_code])}}&php_code=echo "Hi there!"` (url-encode the values first)

Comment: Not quite true. Because of the string interpolation of `"$2"` your code never gets executed. It gets interpolated into the second value of the array.

Comment: I tried something along the lines of `$arg = '09", exit, "';`. I expected it to work. The preg_replace outputs the intended malicious code: `list($var, $var2) = array("09", "", exit, "")` but because of the string interpolation `$var2 === '", exit, "'`.

Comment: So as @Uriziel demonstrated the code can be exploited for data read/tampering exploits. But apparently syntactic escape exploits aren't viable -- only because of the variable interpolation not because `/e` would be safe in itself.

Comment: *"I'm sure preg_replace is often used in with the modifier e"* ... no, it isn't. The 'e' modifier has been considered poor practice for a long time, and is formally deprecated in recent PHP versions (ie it will throw an E_DEPRECATED error message unless you explicitly configure PHP to ignore it). I've personally worked full-time as a PHP developer for a decade and I've never once seen the 'e' modifier in use in the wild. `preg_replace_callback()`, yes, but never the 'e modifier.

Comment: If you replace (.+) with ([a-z]+) then there is no security issue.

Comment: @Spudley I've seen a pretty cool base64_decode type virus being executed via `/e`. There was no `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode("viruscodehere")))` because the `/e` took care of the eval, `gzinflate` and `base64_decode` were written using characters by code (`\xAA`). Which meant it was better hidden from a simple search by `eval` + `gzinflate` + `base64_decode`.

Comment: @B.Martin Indeed, I can't think of any way of breaking out of it if you only use highly restrictive character classes to compose your `eval` string. Still, I can see very little reason **not** to switch to `preg_replace_callback`, and plenty of scope for making mistakes using `/e`. The PHP maintainers clearly agree, and plan to force your hand in a future version.

Comment: That's a good point. I will definately not use it anymore. It's interesting to see that WordPress and phpbb among others have been using `preg_replace_callback` with `/e`. Google shows a lot of results for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
(.+)
```

with **/e** parameter is always exploitable because it allows any language constructions there.

Example exploit code:

```
$test = new test();
$test->setSuperSecret();
$test->exploitableExpression();

class test
{
    private $mySuperSecretVariable;
    public function exploitableExpression()
    {
        $arg= '1234$this->mySuperSecretVariable';
        preg_replace("/([0-9]+)(.+)/e",'list($var,$var2)=array("$1","$2")',$arg);
        var_dump($var,$var2);
    }
    public function setSuperSecret()
    {
        $this->mySuperSecretVariable = 'SECRET!';
    }
}
```

Comment: ...which in turn is exploitable because...?

Comment: Is this a real question ? There is a dosen ways to exploit that, example:
`$test = new test();
$test->setSuperSecret();
$test->exploitableExpression();

class test
{
 private $mySuperSecretVariable;
 public function exploitableExpression()
 {
  $arg= '1234$this->mySuperSecretVariable';
  preg_replace("/([0-9]+)(.+)/e",'list($var,$var2)=array("$1","$2")',$arg);
  var_dump($var,$var2);
 }
 public function setSuperSecret()
 {
  $this->mySuperSecretVariable = 'SECRET!';
 }
}`

Comment: The point was that you didn't supply an explanation. Just saying "it's exploitable" doesn't educate. It creates fear of concepts that can otherwise be used safely -- if you know what you're doing.

Comment: You are right @MihaiStancu Ill try to do better in future (and Ill edit my post to cover the example exploit), thank You.

Comment: My point exactly. It's obvious to anyone that `.+` will match anything. Why that is exploitable in the context of `/e` is not as obvious (even if there's a section in the manual [explaining exactly that](http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval) -- sigh).

Comment: +1 I was testing for code injection via syntactic escape routes. I didn't even think of plain old data tampering :-) kudos!.

Answer (score 3):

The `/e` modifier is very hard to make safe, and it will be removed in a future version of PHP. The reason is that it performs its substitution first *and then* evaluates the code (as though with `eval()`).

It is therefore possible to craft input such that the substituted code runs arbitrary PHP functions or exposes private variables.

Some escaping is performed automatically, but it is insufficient protection, as shown by [this example which executes an arbitrary function using your code](http://3v4l.org/oIT0U) and the [examples in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval):

```
function dangerous()
{
    echo 'Dangerous code executed';
}

$arg = '42{${dangerous()}}';
preg_replace("/([0-9]+)(.+)/e",'list($var, $var2) = array("$1", "$2")', $arg);
var_dump($var, $var2);
```

In contrast, [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) sends the value of the substitution as a parameter to a callback function, so there is no way for the contents of the initial string to be evaluated directly as code.

Note that in your example, the executed code is just assigning variables anyway, so doesn't need any kind of callback, only to capture the matches with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_match("/([0-9]+)(.+)/", $arg, $matches);
$var = $matches[1];
$var2 = $matches[2];
```

Comment: Apparently doing the substitution first and evaluating the code afterwards is not true -- at least on my version 5.5.3 -- otherwise my tests/explanations about syntactic escape exploits and string interpolations wouldn't be true.

Comment: @MihaiStancu See this trivial example: http://3v4l.org/J4J9c The code `preg_replace('/(.+)/e', '$1', $arg);` is equivalent to `eval($arg)`, and anything more complex is simply adding a substitution step *before* the evaluation.

Comment: See this other trivial example: [3v4l.org/eKJKq](http://3v4l.org/eKJKq). Once you get Why it isn't working, you'll get why I said that you have no syntactic escape exploits and that the values of the variables are replaced and interpolated after the code is parsed.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I forgot that PHP attempts to escape, badly, using `addslashes()`. Based on the manual, I have added an example of how to break out of double-quoted strings. [Here is the equivalent attack on your example](http://3v4l.org/DYkUg).

Comment: that's true -- so we can exploit reading variables and we can exploit executing functions and perhaps anything that can be run within a string interpolator which means we're still in a syntactically bound cage -- a bit bigger indeed..

Comment: @MihaiStancu Yeah, it's a bit like SQL injection - you need to work out the context you're executing in, but with a bit of creativity and a strong knowledge of the underlying parser you can often generate some pretty nasty esaclations.